# How to use classes of library B which is included in library A in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, gradle, dependencies

I built 'library A' which relies on 'com.android.support:custom tabs:23.1.1', i.e.,

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:23.1.1'
}
```

'library A' is located in 'Project My'.

I added module 'demo' in 'Project My', and in build.gradle of module 'demo',I imported 'library A' as a local library

```
dependencies {
compile project(':library A')
// notice that no compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:23.1.1' here.
}
```

Then I could use classes in 'com.android.support:customtabs:23.1.1', it was totally right.

---

Later on, I published 'library A' on both JCenter and MavenCentral, so we can import 'library A' with a single line

```
compile 'com.XXX.XXX:library A:1.0.0'
```

---

Then I created a new 'Project My2', in it's build.gradle, I added

```
compile 'com.XXX.XXX:library A:1.0.0'
```

## But

I couldn't use classes in 'com.android.support:customtabs:23.1.1'. And I wanna know how can I use classes in 'com.android.support:customtabs:23.1.1' without adding

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:23.1.1'
}
```

in build.gradle of 'Project My2'.

Comment: it should be correct. Check in the maven repo the pom file. You should see the dependencies block.

Comment: Agreed. It feels like your POM is missing its dependency information. You may wish to post enough of your `build.gradle` file to show how you published this library. And, since the library itself is obviously public, you might consider just linking to it (rather than going the `com.XXX.XXX` route), as it will be easier for us to help you if we can see the library that is giving you trouble.

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti Thanks for your help, it turns out that my pom file did lose dependency information, and I've fix the problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare It turns out my pom file did lose dependency information, and I've fix the problem. Thanks very much.